# Making `Identifiable` protocol backwards compatible

Tags: ios, swift

**Problem**

Apple made `Identifiable` only available in iOS 13+. It's a super useful protocol, however I ended up using my own "Identifiable" protocol named `CompatibilityIdentifiable`.

```swift
public protocol CompatibilityIdentifiable {
    associatedtype Id: Equatable
    var id: Id { get }
}
```

**Question**:

Is there any way to make my custom `CompatibilityIdentifiable` also conform to `Identifiable` on iOS 13+?

**Background:**

In a regular project this has no use. But in an SPM package it means a lot because I can implement the same behaviour for `CompatibilityIdentifiable` as for `Identifiable` without duplicating my code.

Here is an example:

```swift
extension TableViewHelper where Section: CompatibilityIdentifiable {
    public func replace(sections: [Section], with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation = .automatic) {
        replaceSections(with: animation) { oldSection in
            return sections.first(where: { $0.id == oldSection.id })
        }
    }
}
```

If I can simply make `CompatibilityIdentifiable` conform to `Identifiable` I can use `Identifiable` for projects that are iOS 13+

I honestly don't think this is possible unless I simply copy and paste the code like this:

```swift
@available(iOS 13, *)
extension TableViewHelper where Section: Identifiable {
    public func replace(sections: [Section], with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation = .automatic) {
        replaceSections(with: animation) { oldSection in
            return sections.first(where: { $0.id == oldSection.id })
        }
    }
}
```

I won't be doing this as we're talking about a lot of functions. So, if there is no way, I will continue using `CompatibilityIdentifiable` for my future projects and my SPMs

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no way to make your protocol inherit from `Identifiable`, but only from iOS 13 and above.

The reason is you cannot have two declarations of the same protocol, one for iOS 12-, and one for iOS 13+.

With Objective-C protocols, this might have been possible via some `#ifdef` dance, but since `Identifiable` is a Swift-only protocol, and since you're targeting a Swift package, you're out of luck.

However, if you refactor your code a little bit, you might be able to support both `Identifiable`, and `CompatibilityIdentifiable` with less duplication:

```swift
extension Array where Element: CompatibilityIdentifiable {
    func firstWithSameId(as other: Element) {
       first(where: { $0.id == other.id })
    }
}

extension Array where Element: Identifiable {
    func firstWithSameId(as other: Element) {
       first(where: { $0.id == other.id })
    }
}

extension TableViewHelper {
    // mind the `internal` access modifier here (explicitly written)
    internal func replaceSection(with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation, replacement: (Section) -> Section?) {
        replaceSections(with: animation) { replacement($0) })
        // or replaceSections(with: animation, secondParam: replacement)
    }

    public func replace(sections: [Section], with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation = .automatic) where Section: CompatibilityIdentifiable {
        replaceSections(with: animation, replacement: sections.firstWithSameId)
    }

    @available(iOS 13, *)
    public func replace(sections: [Section], with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation = .automatic) where Section: Identifiable {
        replaceSections(with: animation, replacement: sections.firstWithSameId)
    }
}
```

Even if the two public functions looks the same, they have only one line of code, which is easier to grasp in the economy of code duplication.

Also there's more code than by simply copy+pasting, however the two `Array` extensions might be usable in other context too.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and suggestion. I'll give that a shot and see where it takes me.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as `$0.id` will never never work as `.id` doesn't exist on the Section (`$0`) unless I conform to `Identifiable` or `CompatibilityIdentifiable`. In addition the `replace` callback expects a section to be returned so passing an array of IDs is not enough.

Comment: Thank you @Cristik. I didn't expect many (or any) answers and the problem isn't a real big deal....ill just work around it.

Comment: @Jacob I updated the answer, should work now for you. Note that I wrote the code in the SO editor, so minor typos can be still present.

Comment: It's an interesting solution @Cristik. I tried to play around with this but I just don't find its very usable for more complex scenarios like I have. Here is exactly what  I am dealing with: https://github.com/cuba/Canoe/blob/master/Sources/Canoe/TableViewHelper.swift. Honestly I think ill keep using my custom `CompatibilityIdentifiable` (renamed to `TableViewHelperIdentifiable`) but ill keep some of what you wrote in mind. I greatly appreciate the time and effort.

Comment: @Jacob yeah, the solution does add more cognitive load on the readers and maintainers of the  code...